# Print odd-numbered lines, print even-numbered lines

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to print the odd-numbered and even-numbered lines from files.

I found this shell script which makes use of echo.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Write a shell script that, given a file name as the argument will write
# the even numbered line to a file with name evenfile and odd numbered lines
# in a text file called oddfile.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2001 nixCraft project <http://cyberciti.biz/fb/>
# This script is licensed under GNU GPL version 2.0 or above
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This script is part of nixCraft shell script collection (NSSC)
# Visit http://bash.cyberciti.biz/ for more information.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

file=$1
counter=0

eout="evenfile.$$" # even file name
oout="oddfile.$$" # odd file name

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "$(basename $0) file"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f $file ]
then
    echo "$file not a file"
    exit 2
fi

while read line
do
    # find out odd or even line number
    isEvenNo=$( expr $counter % 2 )

    if [ $isEvenNo -ne 0 ]
    then
        # even match
        echo $line >> $eout
    else
        # odd match
        echo $line >> $oout
    fi
    # increase counter by 1
    (( counter ++ ))
done < $file
echo "Even file - $eout"
echo "Odd file - $oout"
```

But isn't there a way to do it in one line?

*Yes, use awk,* I read.

Even-numbered lines:

```
awk 'NR % 2' filename
```

odd-numbered lines:

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 1' filename
```

But it doesn't work for me. Both produce the same output, according to diff. When compared to the original file, they are both indeed half as long, and they both contain the odd-numbered lines. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The first one should be `NR % 2 == 0`, otherwise it is equivalent to the second one.

Comment: There seem to be several documents online (including this one) that show up at the top of a search that state that NR % 2 gives you the even numbered lines, which is not correct, it gives you the odd because 1 % 2 = 1 = true, 2 % 2 = 0 = false.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you asked “in one line”:

```
awk '{print>sprintf("%sfile.%d",NR%2?"odd":"even",PROCINFO["pid"])}' filename
```

Note that most of the code is due to your fancy output filename choice. Otherwise the following code would be enough to put odd lines in “line-1” and even lines in “line-0”:

```
awk '{print>"line-"NR%2}' filename
```

Answer (score 53):

I prefer to be POSIX compatible, whenever possible, so I thought I'd post this alternative method.  I often use these to mangle text, before `xargs` pipelines.

#### Print Even Numbered Lines,

```
sed -n 'n;p'
```

#### Print Odd Numbered Lines,

```
sed -n 'p;n'
```

Although I often use `awk`, it's overkill for this type of task.

Comment: Here is an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614959/display-one-line-of-two-with-sed#:~:text=sed%20%2Dn%20'p%3Bn',-%2Dn%20suppresses%20all&text=p%20prints%20the%20current%20line,again%20on%20this%20new%20line.

Comment: There's also `sed 'n;d'`. Do note that `sed 'd;n'` won't work. Because `d` starts a [next cycle](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/sed/sed.1.en#d).

Answer (score 21):

For even numbers the code should be

```
awk 'NR%2==0' filename
```

& for odd numbers

```
awk 'NR%2==1' filename
```

Comment: this one is perfect. Even works if you need to get rows in increment of 10, say you need to reduce a ordered file of size 1million to 100k. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: How can you print the even-numbered columns in AWK? I cannot get this working `gawk 'FS=",";NF%2==0' file.csv`.

Answer (score 17):

That's easy:

```
 sed -n 2~2p filename
```

will print even-numbered lines from filename

```
sed -n 1~2p filename
```

will print odd-numbered lines.

Comment: +1, for not using AWK extraneously.  Not POSIX sed, but it's still solid method.

Comment: @TechZilla I don't understand "using AWK extraneously" - awk is POSIX as well.

Comment: @jw013: Nothing is wrong with `awk`, personally I use it very often.  I never said anything was 'Not POSIX' about `awk`, I was referring to the answer's `sed` options.  Specifically the `~` operator, it's a GNU extension, which is still acceptable for many people. Regarding 'using AWK extraneously`, I personally believe using `awk` for this simple task is overkill.  So the +1 was for for completing the task with `sed`, a lighter utility than `awk`.

Comment: Can someone please explain how ~ operator works here?

Comment: first~step
              Match  every  step'th line starting with line first.  For example, ``sed -n 1~2p'' will print all the odd-numbered lines in the input stream,
              and the address 2~5 will match every fifth line, starting with the second.  first can be zero; in this case, sed operates as if it were equal
              to step.  (This is an extension.)  @ForeverLearner

Comment: Note, this does not work on mac becuase of sed version.  Use sed -n 'n;p' on mac system.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a single `sed` invocation, no need to read the file twice:

```
sed '$!n
w even
d' infile > odd
```

or, if you prefer in one line:

```
sed -e '$!n' -e 'w even' -e d infile > odd
```

Note that these won't give the expected result if a file contains only one line (the line will be `w`ritten to `even` instead of `odd` as the first `n` isn't executed). To avoid that, add a condition:

```
sed -e '$!n' -e '1!{w even' -e 'd}' infile > odd
```

---

How it works ? Well, it uses three `sed` commands:
`n` - if not on the last line *print* the pattern space to `stdout`(which is redirected to file `odd`), replace it with the next line (so now it's processing an even line) and continue executing the remaining commands
`w` - append the pattern space to file `even`
`d` - delete current pattern space and restart the cycle - the side effect of this is that `sed` will never auto-print the pattern space as it never reaches the end of script

In other words, `n` is executed only on odd lines and `w` and `d` are executed only on even lines. `sed` never gets to autoprint unless, as I said, the input consists of a single line.

Comment: Thanks a lot  don_crissti for your help. Sincerely appreciate it, upvoted as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '{if(NR%2){print $0 > "odd.file"}else{print $0 > "even.file"}}' filename
```

Comment: Are you sure about outputting the record numbers?

Comment: sorry about that, I modified it to output the whole lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with `perl` because I like `perl`:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{open($e,">even_lines");open($o,">odd_lines")} $. % 2 ?select $o:select $e;'
```

Uses the fact that `-p` implicitly prints, to replicated how `sed` works - and we use `select` to choose which file handle to which it writes.

Comment: One alternate, that will do either odd or even (not both) would be to change the command line to `perl -ne 'print if $. % 2 == 1'` for odd and `perl -ne 'print if $. % 2 == 0'` for even. That doesn't do both simultaneously, but for smaller files, it's quick enough to run twice.

Answer (score 0):

Print even-numbered lines:

```
awk 'getline' file
```

Print odd-numbered lines:

```
awk '{print; getline}' file
```