# Write data to both a file and a serial port — can I use tee?

Tags: cat, serial-port, tee

I am trying to take the input from a serial port and write it to a file and also then read the file and send it back out the serial port to the host computer. A coworker suggested using the "tee" command but I can't find a good example/wrap my mind around the command. Is it possible to do this with "tee"? it seems that tee can only do one command, like cating a file to a different place, but not cating the port then writing to the document then reading the document and then sending it over the port. Or am i just not understanding the basics of the "tee" command.

Comment: `tee` can take multiple output file arguments, which in this case would be the output file and the serial port.

Comment: Oh awesome. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Related, but overkill here: [How can I send stdout to multiple commands?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28503)

Answer (score 1):

The `tee` command writes the input to standard output as well as to a file at the same time. A quick example would be

```
$ echo "Hi there..."|tee -a hi.txt
Hi there....
$cat hi.txt
Hi there....
```

In the above, example it presents the text in STDOUT and writes it to `hi.txt`.
Another example could be

```
$cat hi.txt|tee -a final.txt
Hi there.....
$cat final.txt
Hi there....
```

So considering bash shell, your example could be-

```
$cat ./serial-port|tee -a <filename>
```

So if serial-port is 20002 then the above command would look like

```
$cat $serial-port|tee -a serial.txt
20002
$cat serial.txt
20002
```

Comment: And to pipe write it back to another serialport you would `cat ./serial-port | tee -a localcopy.txt | ./outgoing-serial-port` ... I think the OP wants to do that.

Comment: Yeah that is pretty much exactly what I want to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: When I run the command it says that ttyUSB0 directory doesn't exist. Did I do something wrong? 
cat ./ttyUSB0 | tee -a local.txt | ./ttyUSB0

Comment: i think you want to do something like `cat ./ttyUSB0 | tee -a local.txt > ./ttyUSB0`

Comment: Just to be clear... pipe sends the output of one command to another command in this case `cat ./ttyUSB0 | tee -a local.txt | ./ttyUSB0` ./ttyUSB0 is not a command, rather maybe a file (or port). So in order to write the output back to the file (or port) u have to use `>` redirect operator