# how to move (not copy) files from one server to another?

Tags: shell-script, rsync

I want to move files from *server1* to *server2*.

A producer on *server1* will keep generating the files, and a consumer on *server2* will keep processing them.

I can copy files using the following shell script:

```
rsync path/*.txt server2:/path
```

The extension of the files on the destination (*server2*) will be changed from .txt  to .done once they are processed, so if I run the command again, the files will once again copied (and processed) to the destination.

Hence, I want to delete (or rename or move) the original files so that they won't be transferred again.

I am using `rsync` version 2.6.3, which does not have --remove-source-files option.

I am new to shell scripting, so please give an example.

Answer (score 2):

use `rsync` `--remove-source-files` option

from `man rsync`

```
--remove-source-files
This  tells  rsync  to  remove  from  the sending side the files
(meaning non-directories) that are a part of  the  transfer  and
have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side.
```

You can always perform a trial run with no changes made using `--dry-run` option and If you like output run the final command without `--dry-run`option

for example:`rsync --remove-source-files -options /path/to/src/ computerB:/path/to/dest` and also take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/342729/how-safe-is-rsync-remove-source-files) question before proceeding.

Comment: rsync version 2.6.3 does not have this option. I don't think I have permission to update rsync.

Comment: You can use `tee` and process substitution for this. for eg: use `find` to find your files and use `tee` to send the output to both `rsync` and `rm` see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands)

Answer (score 1):

According to the `man`-page, you should be able to use `--remove-source-files` for `rsync`

> **--remove-source-files**
>
> This tells rsync to remove from the sending side the files (meaning non-directories) that are a part of the transfer and have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side.

Comment: rsync version 2.6.3 does not have this option. I don't think I have permission to update rsync.

Comment: @prodigy2050 Hmm, I do not have an alternative for you in that case.