# Pipe to multiple files in the shell

Tags: bash, shell, grep, pipe

I have an application which will produce a large amount of data which I do not wish to store onto the disk. The application mostly outputs data which I do not wish to use, but a set of useful information that must be split into separate files. For example, given the following output:

```
JUNK
JUNK
JUNK
JUNK
A 1
JUNK
B 5
C 1
JUNK
```

I could run the application three times like so:

```
./app | grep A > A.out
./app | grep B > B.out
./app | grep C > C.out
```

This would get me what I want, but it would take too long. I also don't want to dump all the outputs to a single file and parse through that.

Is there any way to combine the three operations shown above in such a way that I only need to run the application once and still get three separate output files?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you have **tee**

```bash
./app | tee >(grep A > A.out) >(grep B > B.out) >(grep C > C.out) > /dev/null
```

(from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28519/33933))

([about process substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution))

Comment: Awesome, this could also be rendered as: `./app | tee >(grep A > A.out) >(grep B > B.out) | grep C > C.out`

Comment: This answer is currently the only accurate one, given the question's original title "pipe to multiple processes".

Comment: +1. This is the most generally-applicable answer, since it doesn't depend on the fact that the specific filtering command was `grep`.

Comment: I would agree that this is the best answer for the question posed and should be marked so.  *Parallel* is another solution (as posted) but having done some timed comparisons the above example is more efficient. If the op instead involved highly cpu intensive operations such as multiple file compression or multiple mp3 conversion then no doubt the *parallel* solution should prove to be more effective.

Answer (score 32):

You can use `awk`

```bash
./app | awk '/A/{ print > "A.out"}; /B/{ print > "B.out"}; /C/{ print > "C.out"}'
```

Comment: The question's title is pipe to multiple **processes**, this answer is about "piping" (dispatching by regex) to multiple **files**. Since this answer was accepted, the question's title should be changed accordingly.

Comment: @PauloMadeira You are right. What do you think would be a better title?

Comment: I've suggested a very small edit "Pipe to multiple files in the shell", it's pending revision, check it out. I was expecting to remove the comment if it was accepted.

Comment: @PauloMadeira - I've changed the title. Didn't see your edit, but you're correct, the use of processes in the title was incorrect if this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

You could also use your shell's [pattern matching abilities](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns):

```
./app | while read line; do 
     [[ "$line" =~ A ]] && echo $line >> A.out; 
     [[ "$line" =~ B ]] && echo $line >> B.out; 
     [[ "$line" =~ C ]] && echo $line >> C.out; 
 done
```

Or even:

```
./app | while read line; do for foo in A B C; do 
     [[ "$line" =~ "$foo" ]] && echo $line >> "$foo".out; 
  done; done
```

A safer way that can deal with backslashes and lines starting with `-`:

```
./app | while IFS= read -r line; do for foo in A B C; do 
     [[ "$line" =~ "$foo" ]] && printf -- "$line\n" >> "$foo".out; 
  done; done
```

As @StephaneChazelas points out in the comments, this is not very efficient. The best solution is probably [@AurélienOoms'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97713/22222).

Comment: That assumes the input doesn't contain backslashes or blanks or wildcard characters, or lines that start with `-n`, `-e`... It's also going to be terribly inefficient as it means several system calls per line (one `read(2)` per character, the file being open, writing closed for each line...). Generally, using `while read` loops to process text in shells is bad practice.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I edited my answer. It should work with backslashes and `-n` etc now. As far as I can tell both versions work OK with blanks though, am I wrong?

Comment: No, the first argument to `printf` is the format. There's no reason for leaving you variables unquoted in there.

Comment: This will also break in bash (and other shells that use cstrings in a similar way) if there are nulls in the input.

Answer (score 9):

If you have multiple cores and you want the processes to be in parallel, you can do:

```
parallel -j 3 -- './app | grep A > A.out' './app | grep B > B.out' './app | grep C > C.out'
```

This will spawn three processes in parallel cores.  If you want there to be some output to the console, or a master file, it has the advantage of keeping the output in some order, rather that mixing it.

The gnu utility **parallel** from Ole Tange can be obtained from most repos under the name **parallel** or **moreutils**.  Source can be obtained from [Savannah.gnu.org](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel/).  Also an introductory instructional video is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ).

**Addendum**

Using the more recent version of parallel (not necessarily the version in your distribution repo), you can use the more elegant construct:

```
./app | parallel -j3 -k --pipe 'grep {1} >> {1}.log' ::: 'A' 'B' 'C'
```

Which achieves the result of running one ./app and 3 parallel grep processes in separate cores or threads (as determined by parallel itself, also consider the -j3 to be optional, but it is supplied in this example for instructive purposes).

The newer version of parallel can be obtained by doing:

```
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/parallel/parallel-20131022.tar.bz2
```

Then the usual unpack, cd to parallel-{date}, ./configure && make, sudo make install.  This will install parallel, man page parallel and man page parallel_tutorial.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one in Perl:

```
./app | perl -ne 'BEGIN {open(FDA, ">A.out") and 
                         open(FDB, ">B.out") and 
                         open(FDC, ">C.out") or die("Cannot open files: $!\n")} 
                  print FDA $_ if /A/; print FDB $_ if /B/; print FDC $_ if /C/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -ne/A/w\ A.out -e/B/w\ B.out -e/C/p <in >C.out
```

...if `<in` is readable all three outfiles will be truncated before anything is written to them.