# How to give stdout to different program on same line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, stdout, programming

I could do it long way i.e

```bsh
cat hi.txt | grep 'important url' > imurl
cat hi.txt | grep -v 'not important url' > imnoturl
cat hi.txt | otherprogram1
cat hi.txt | otherprogramN
```

However, is there anycommand that allows me to do it in one line. Just curiosity not a neccessity.
Like:
`cat hi.txt | someprogram -p1 ' grep "important url" > imurl ' -p2 ' grep -v "not important url" > imnoturl ' -p3 ' other task ' -pn ''`

Edit:
I want to merge this two:

```bsh
cat $fdns_w1 | pigz -dc | fgrep ".$1" | awk -F 'name":"' '{print $2}' | awk -F '","type' '{print $1}' | sort -u
cat $fdns_w1 | pigz -dc | fgrep ".$1" | awk -F 'value":"' '{print $2}' | awk -F '"}' '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

Comment: `<hi.txt tee >(grep ...)`: [Pipe to multiple files in the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97705/pipe-to-multiple-files-in-the-shell).

Comment: Nice hmm probably a duplicate i think my question

Comment: Thanks bro  will try it soon, please answer the question @guest