# Command redirection to multiple files: command >file1 >file2

Tags: shell, command-line, io-redirection

I have this command:

```
cat somefile >file1 >file2
```

After I executed this command I can't figure out why `file1` has nothing in it. It should have the output of the first file (`somefile`), but nothing is in it.

Can you explain to me why it does not copy or write my output from `somefile`? (`file2` contains my output, but `file1` contains nothing)

Comment: A `>` redirects the output to a file, period. Use `tee(1)` if you want to duplicate output to a file and send it on.

Comment: In sh and bash (and probably others) you can open multiple output files like so: `cat somefile >file1 3>file2 4>file3`. This means you start the program with two extra files opened as fileno 3 and fileno 4. Of course,`cat` will ignore those, but it can be useful if you want to have different log files, for example, or you're somehow splitting the input in 3 parts, etc.

Comment: **The question here is "WHY doesn't this work as I expected?", NOT "how to make it work?" the [alleged duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28503/108618) asks.** None of the answers there explain why multiple redirections work as they work, so none of the answers there answers *this* question. "Fixing" this by answering this question there makes no sense because that question absolutely does not ask what this question asks. The two questions are related and linking them is a good idea (in terms of "linked" in the right column →), but they are not duplicates. **I'm voting to reopen.**

Answer (score 16):

I think there's a difference between how you think shell redirection works and how it really does.

Except in `zsh` (which implements a `tee`-like behaviour behind the seen when output is redirected more than once), you cannot redirect the output of the shell multiple times and expect it to be redirected to all the locations you've specified. Instead, it will only be redirected to the last location, which in your case is `file2`. The answer by Chaos provides a decent explanation on how such I/O Redirection works.

What you really want to do is:

```
$ cat example.txt | tee file1 > file2
```

`tee` is a program that reads from the standard input and writes to multiple file descriptors. One of them is *always* the standard output. So we use `tee` to write the output to `file1` and then redirect its stdout to `file2`.

Also, based on suggestions in the comments, this is a better way to do what you're looking for:

```
$ tee file1 < example.txt > file2
```

That approach has the advantage that it redirects the `stdin` instead of trying to read over a pipe. That means that the shell now needs to spawn one fewer process. It also eliminates what is known as "Useless use of cat". By placing the output redirection *after* the input redirection, we avoid the output files being clobbered if the input file cannot be opened.

Comment: Better, `tee file1 >file2 <example.txt`

Comment: I much prefer the `cat ... | tee` approach. Maybe the cat is useless, but it is much easier for me to follow. Is your system really so constrained that firing off an extra `cat` process is going to be an issue??

Comment: I agree that the `cat ... | tee ` approach is cleaner. Also, a system is barely ever so constrained that it cannot handle the extra call to `cat`. It's however another option.

Comment: If you really want a clean tee command, write it as `< example.txt tee > file1 file2` This can be translated to the human saying of "Using example.txt tee it to file1 and file2"

Comment: @roaima: I presume the `cat` is not really a UUOC but a placeholder for some more complicated command.  (Anybody who actually wanted to copy the contents of a file to two other files would just use `cp` twice.) Omitting it obscures the general principle being used.

Answer (score 10):

What you did, is called [I/O-Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). `>file` redirects the standard output (stdout) to the given `file`. In you case you did that 2 times. The shell doesn't handle a redirection of the same output multiple times .

In this case:

```
cat somefile >file1 >file2
```

The shell processes the redirections before the command (`cat somefile`) is executed. That means the `>` truncates file to zero length, because you override the files content. The file must be empty before the shell can execute the command. This is done with both `>` redirections.

Now, the second one (`>file2`) overrides the first one (`>file1`), because the shell processes the redirection in order of appearance. So, the last one is the one that will effectvely be used. The output of `cat somefile` will therefore be redirected to `file2` and `file1` will be truncated to zero length.

---

Redirecting stdout to multiple processes/files can be done with `tee` like this:

```
cat somefile | tee file1 file2 file3 fileX
```

This will print the contents to stdout *and* to all files given as paramters.

Comment: Oh, it handles redirection of the same output multiple times.  It's just doesn't handle it the way the OP expected it to. ;-)  (You actually describe well how it's handled.)

Comment: It might be better to do something like `tee <somefile >file1 file2`, since `cat somefile | tee file1 file2 file3 fileX` dumps the contents of `somefile` to your terminal and doesn't really need the `cat` call.

Comment: Note that `zsh` can be used with multiple `>file{1,2,3}` and it works as if you used `tee`.

Answer (score 3):

In `zsh` with [MULTIOS option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#index-multios) set (as it is by default), you can use:

```
cat somefile >file1 >file2
```

as in that case, `zsh` performs an action similar to `tee` behind the scene. Or even:

```
<somefile >file1 >file2
```

as the default value of `$NULLCMD`, the command run when there are redirections without command happens to be `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cat somefile >file1 >file2
> ```

Without redirections `cat somefile` would inherit stdin from the shell. Usually stdin of a shell is not closed, it already points to some file. A terminal is also a [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). When you run `cat somefile` in an interactive shell whose stdout is your terminal, the output of `cat` goes to the terminal. In general the stdout of the shell may be something else, irrelevant, `cat` will inherit it anyway.

What `cat somefile >file1` does is it makes the shell:

- try to open `file1` for writing (it creates the file if it's not already there) and to truncate it to zero size (if possible); this happens before `cat` is started;
- set up `file1` as stdout for the future `cat`, so the `cat` will use `file1` *instead of* what it would use without the redirection (you don't expect `cat somefile >file1` to also write to your terminal, right?).

The redirection redirects. :) The current direction is "to the terminal", the new direction is "to `file1`". The new direction is taken *instead of* the current direction and the new direction becomes current.

The shell parses redirections from left to right. In case of `cat somefile >file1 >file2` the shell first handles `>file1` in the way described above. Then it handles `>file2` *in the same way*: it opens and truncates the file, and sets up "to `file2`" for the future `cat` *instead of* the current direction which at this point is already "to `file1`". This way "to `file2`" replaces "to `file1`" and becomes current, exactly like "to `file1`" replaced  "to the terminal" a moment ago.

You can add more `>fileN` redirections and each one will be handled in the described way. Assuming each one succeeds, the last one will win. In your case `>file2` wins.

After all the redirections are handled, `cat` is started. Your `cat` sees `file2` as its stdout and it's not even aware `file1` was involved in any way. The truncation of `file1` is a "side effect", it's only because `>file1` has been parsed by the shell, it has nothing to do with `cat`.

<sup>You can use this mechanism to create/truncate one or more files: `: >file1 >file2 …` will try to truncate the files. `:` is a no-op, it doesn't even use its stdout. Creating and truncating happens when the shell handles the redirections before starting `:`.</sup>

---

This is how output redirections work in `sh` and compatible shells. The MULTIOS option in `zsh` (see [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235161/108618)) is different: the first redirection replaces the old direction (e.g. the terminal) while consecutive redirections *add* directions. How it happens under the hood, I won't elaborate. I just want to point out that the behavior you observed emerges from the fact in `sh` (or in a compatible shell) each `>fileN` is handled *independently*, one after another; but in `zsh` there's a mode where it treats multiple output redirections more like a unit.