# dash: Pipe STDIN to multiple commands and their output to STDOUT in defined order

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, file-descriptors, tee, dash

At first I thought [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43536/118329) was the solution, but now I think I need a temporary file as buffer.

This works unreliably:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo 'OK' |
{
    {
        tee /dev/fd/3 | head --bytes=1 >&4
    } 3>&1 | tail --bytes=+2 >&4
} 4>&1
```

When I run this in a terminal, sometimes I get:

> OK

and sometimes I get:

> K
>   O

Seems totally random. So as a workaround I'm writing the output of `tail` to a file and reading it back to `stdout` after the pipe has finished.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo 'OK' |
{
    {
        tee /dev/fd/3 | head --bytes=1 >&4
    } 3>&1 | tail --bytes=+2 >file
} 4>&1
cat file
```

Can this be done in `dash` without temporary files? Shell variables as buffer aren't an option either, as the output might contain NUL bytes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send stdout to multiple commands?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands)

Comment: There's multiple other solutions in the post, including named pipes and process substitution with `bash` . Try them first

Comment: Thanks @Serg, as I'm using `dash` I don't have access to process substitution. (I added `dash` to the title.) With named pipes I have the exact same problem (arbitrary order of execution).

Comment: OK, very good.  That's going to be relevant info. I'll see what I can do about `dash` then

Comment: Any time you're running multiple processes in parallel the ordering of output is going to be unspecified.

Comment: That's what I feared. So I'm going to need a buffer. Guess I'll fix something with `mktemp -d` on `/dev/shm`. Any better ideas?

Comment: So, I've posted an answer on the linked question. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342717/85039  See if that works for you. Of course, it's for relatively small output, doesn't work if you have huge amount of data that you need to give to multiple commands, but in your specific case should work. I tested that with `dash` on my system as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to run the consumers and producer in parallel, but serialize the output of the consumers, you'd need to delay the output of the second consumer. For that, you'd need to store its output somehow and the best way is with a temporary file.

With `zsh`:

```
{cat =(producer > >(consumer1 >&3) | consumer2)} 3>&1
```

[`bash` has an issue in that it doesn't wait for the process substitution commands, so you'd have to use nasty work arounds there](/a/388530).

Here, we're using the `=(...)` form of process substitution to store the output of `comsumer2` in a temporary file and `cat` it afterwards. We can't do that for more than 2 consumers. For that, we'd need to create the temp files by hand.

When not using `=(...)`, we'd have to handle the clean up of the tempfiles by hand. We can handle that by creating and deleting them up front so not to have to worry about the cases where the script is killed. Still with `zsh`:

```
tmp1=$(mktemp) && tmp2=$(mktemp) || exit
{
  rm -f -- $tmp1 $tmp2
  producer > >(consumer1) > >(consumer2 >&3) > >(consumer3 >&5)
  cat <&4 <&6
} 3> $tmp1 4< $tmp1 5> $tmp2 6< $tmp2
```

---

Edit (I initially missed the fact that a solution for `dash` was required)

For `dash` (or any POSIX shell that doesn't set the close-on-exec flag on fds above 2 and uses pipes and not socketpairs for `|`), and on systems with `/dev/fd/x` support:

```
tmp1=$(mktemp) && tmp2=$(mktemp) || exit
{
  rm -f -- "$tmp1" "$tmp2"
  {
    {
      {
        producer | tee /dev/fd/4 /dev/fd/6 | consumer1 >&7
      } 4>&1 | consumer2 >&3
    } 6>&1 | consumer3 >&5
  } 7>&1
  cat - /dev/fd/6 <&4
} 3> "$tmp1" 4< "$tmp1" 5> "$tmp2" 6< "$tmp2"
```

That would work with `dash`, `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh`, `busybox sh`, `posh` on Linux, but not `ksh93`. That approach can't go beyond 4 consumers as we're limited to fds 0 to 9.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution *is* to use temporary files.  This makes the code readable and easy to understand when process substitution is not an option.

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

producer | tee "$tmpfile" | consumer1
consumer2 <"$tmpfile"

rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

or even

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

producer >"$tmpfile"

consumer1 <"$tmpfile"
consumer2 <"$tmpfile"

rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

Comment: `bash` doesn't use temp files for process substitution. Only temporary named pipes on systems that don't support /dev/fd/n. Only `zsh` (with the `=(...)` syntax) or `fish` (with `psub -f`) can use temp files for process substitutions. It's true though that **the** solution here is to use temp files (not fifos) as we need to run the commands one after the other, not in parallel. Other option would be to run the commands in parallel but with their output to different files which are concatenated afterwards (the first one could be left unredirected). That's what GNU `parallel` does.