# Piping to multiple awk commands

Tags: bash, awk, pipe, stdout, tee

I'm trying to pipe the output of one command to two different `awk` commands. Following [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands) I am using `tee` and process substitution. However, I can't see the output for the substituted process.

```
nvidia-smi | tee >(awk '/ C / {print $6}') | awk '/ C / {print $3}' | xargs -r ps -o user
```

This is supposed to show the users and memory usage for all gpu processes. The memory usage and PID are extracted from `nvidia-smi`, respectively, by `awk '/ C / {print $6}'` and `awk '/ C / {print $3}'` with the latter then being piped to `ps -o user`. The output contains only the users though.

What I would like is

```
<memory-of-process1> <name-of-user-running-process1>
<memory-of-process2> <name-of-user-running-process2>
<memory-of-process3> <name-of-user-running-process3> 
etc
```

and what I am getting is

```
<name-of-user-running-process1>
<name-of-user-running-process2>
<name-of-user-running-process3>
etc
```

I have tried adding `fflush()` or `stdbuf -o0` to the first awk command, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830700/cannot-use-awk-pipe-output).

Comment: There are a few issues with process substitution. It often produces output after the main pipeline terminates and a new shell prompt appears, which indicates it runs in background. I suspect its stdout is therefore disconnected from the terminal. Try redirecting that stream to a file to verify it runs. You might consider tailing that file, although it is not a great solution.

Comment: Yes I can redirect to a file. 
`nvidia-smi | tee >(awk '/ C / {print $6}' > test) | awk '/ C / {print $3}' | xargs -r ps -o user`, and then `cat test` prints the memory usages.

Comment: To achieve the synchronisation at a line level: have awk open a pipe from a ps command, send the pids, and read back the user names internally. You probably want to store all the nvidia data and do this in an END action, rather than run a pipe for each line of input.

Comment: I'm sorry I wouldn't know how to turn what you suggest into a command. Does synchronisation at a line level mean that the name and memory for each proc are printed on the same line? ie, a different issue to the current absence of memory being printed at all

Comment: By the time you get through two separate awks, and xargs, and ps, and pipe buffering, there is no way the awk outputs will arrive in pairs. As it is, each of $6 and $3 will have a newline anyway. I can fake up a tested command in a couple of hour's time, if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks. I'm also seeing that if I replace the first `awk` with `cat` (no arguments), then the user names are printed twice. Like `cat` takes stdout as its input after the `ps` command has run.

Comment: @ludog Actually easier than that: what happens is that the output of the first `awk` is piped to the second `awk`, because the first one inherits the redirection of standard output set by the pipeline. The first `awk` prints one field per line, which gets filtered out by the second `awk` (that single field won't match " C "). To make it work you'll need something along the lines of `echo 0 1 | { tee >(awk '{print $1}' 1>&3) | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -- ps -h -o user -p;  } 3>&1` (look at redirections) but, as Paul_Pedant has pointed out, it won't give you the expected output anyway.

Comment: @fra-san ah yes I see, that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More compact solution using a shell script:

```
nvidia-smi | grep ' C ' | while read _ _ pid _ _ mem; do
    user="$( ps -o user "${pid}" | tail -n +2 )"
    printf '%8s  %6d  %s\n' "${mem}" "${pid}" "${user}"
done
```

Note, this runs three extra processes per pid.

Original solution using `awk`:

```
#! /bin/bash

function nvidia-smi { cat <<'[][]'
A C 937 D E 1.7MB
A C 1232 D E 0.25MB
A E 6112 D E 13MB
A C 2008 D E 437KB
A C 2024 D E 314157
[][]
}

AWK='
/ C / { Pid[NR] = $3; xPid[$3] = NR; Mem[NR] = $6; }
END {
    for (j in Pid) pp = pp "," Pid[j];
    cmd = "ps 2>&1 -o pid,user -p " substr (pp, 2);
    while (cmd | getline) 
        if ($1 in xPid) User[xPid[$1]] = $2;
    close (cmd);
    fmt = "%8s  %6d  %s\n";
    for (j = 1; j <= NR; ++j) 
        if (j in Mem)
            printf (fmt, Mem[j], Pid[j], User[j]);
}
'
    nvidia-smi | awk "${AWK}"
```

The function nvidia-smi just presents some test data -- discard that. You need the AWK variable (12 lines in the multi-line constant between single-quotes) and the brief pipeline below it.

A test. I included the pid that was using the memory:

```
paul $ ./nVid
   1.7MB     937  syslog
  0.25MB    1232  root
   437KB    2008  postfix
  314157    2024  paul
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't say I fully follow the awk code, but it seems this just does everything inside `awk`. I can also confirm it works with the 'real' nvidia-smi, except sometimes the user name is not printed.

282MiB    4611  
  282MiB    4613  
  282MiB   12090  
  282MiB   12091  
  282MiB   12093  
  282MiB   26005  
  282MiB   26009  
 1355MiB    7646  bob
 1355MiB    7648  bob
  347MiB   24436  
 1247MiB    4611  bob
 1247MiB    4613  bob
1287MiB   12090  bob
 1355MiB   24436  bob
 1287MiB   12091  bob
 1287MiB   12093  bob
 1091MiB   26005  bob
 1073MiB   26009  bob

Comment: sorry, there should be newlines in that but I can't format it in a comment

Comment: There is a race condition in there. If a process has just ended, it is possible it was present when nvidia-smi was run but has disappeared by the time ps gets run. I really don't know how transient GPU processes can be: for example, are they only connected while they are actually refreshing something. One fix might be to fetch the whole ps output before and after nvidia runs, and check both lists for the pid.

Comment: Is that data list from one run, or two? Every pid that shows up without a username also shows up again with a user name. 7646 and 7648 only show up once. Possibly the pids are permanent threads, and only get allocated to a username while they are connected.

Comment: That is from one run. Some processes are spread over multiple gpus. It looks like that is the cause, that the second gpu is then printed without a name. Normally, the gpu processes in my case are not transient, ie last several minutes at least.

Comment: Ah yes, the shell script works too. It might be worth moving this more compact solution to the top of your answer?