# seeking solution to avoid multiple execution of linux commands in php script

Tags: shell, io-redirection, php

I have a PHP script which provides some output to angular. That script is useful to get the informations from the Perl script. I'm using `exec()` command to call the scripts in PHP. I'm getting what I want, but the problem is time-consuming. I executing the same script thrice to create the array in php. e.g:

```
exec("/usr/bin/reports -h -r -t ".$this->name." | grep -o '^\S*' | sed '1 d'",$report_id);
exec("/usr/bin/reports -h -r -t ".$this->name." | grep -oP '(?<= ).*' | sed '1 d'",$titles);
exec("/usr/bin/reports -h -r -n ".$this->name." | grep -oP '(?<= ).*' | sed '1 d'",$fullnames);
```

As you can see I'm executing the same script multiple times only because of changing parameters.

By first command I'm storing `report_id`, the second command to store their position and third is for their full names. I need a solution to comprise these three commands into one. Please help to avoid the time complexity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send stdout to multiple commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands)

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest to use AWK, it can parse multiple regexs and separates the fields automatically. It easy and small language available in all Unix, created especially for such jobs.
2. A better way is to get the output and do your processing with the PHP. [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) returns the output in array of lines. [preg_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) can do the grep/sed/cut job.
3. You can use the tee command to use the output of reports in multiple pipes.
4. Finally, you can use a customized lock mechanism, but I do not suggest it.