# How might I direct the output of "wget -qO- whatever.tar.gz" to both tar and sha256sum?

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, tar, wget, tee

The following creates `csfile` with a hash in it, unpacks `go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz` [downloaded from Golang's official website](https://go.dev/dl),
prints out the checksum to stdout and then removes the no longer needed `csfile`:

```
wget -qO- https://go.dev/dl/go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz|tee >(sha256sum>csfile) |tar -xz && cat csfile && rm csfile
```

I would like to get the checksum on my screen and the archive unpacked without creating a file like `csfile`. Is it doable?
Based on [some](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833070/how-would-i-pass-the-output-of-one-command-to-multiple-commands) [research that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands) I did I've tried the following two one-liners (to no avail - although the archive gets unpacked, binary output is spitted out to the screen):

```
wget -qO- https://go.dev/dl/go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz|tee >(sha256sum) >(sudo tar -xz>/dev/null)
wget -qO- https://go.dev/dl/go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz|tee >(sudo tar -xz>/dev/null) >(sha256sum)
```

On the other hand, neither of the following two one-liners does upack the archive, but both of them do produce the checksum after spitting out the binary output:

```
wget -qO- https://go.dev/dl/go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz|tee >(xargs tar -xz) >(sha256sum)
wget -qO- https://go.dev/dl/go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz|tee >(sudo xargs tar -xz>/dev/null) >(sha256sum)
```

Why is the binary output spitted out on the screen? Is it spitted by `tar` or by `sha256sum`? I would rather avoid using `sudo` if doable. How might I direct the output of `wget` to both `tar` and `sha256sum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect the output of `sha256sum` to `/dev/tty` to print it on screen, like:

```
wget -qO- https://go.dev/dl/go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz|tee >(sha256sum > /dev/tty) |tar -xz
```

It looks like the following code also works, just put tar in process substitution and sha256sum after the pipe. On my computer, binary output isn't spitted out to the screen tho.

```
wget -qO- https://go.dev/dl/go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz | tee >(tar -xz) | sha256sum
```

I have no idea why it works or not, just trial and error.