# Send stdout to multiple downstream processes in a chain

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout

I have a series of commands I run like this:

```
cmd1 < input > foo
cmd2 < foo > bar
cmd3 foo bar > output
```

Is there a way to do this without the intermediate files `foo` and `bar`?

I'd also like to avoid running `cmd1` twice:

```
cmd3 <(cmd1 < input) <(cmd1 < input | cmd2) > output
```

All 3 commands can take hours to run, and file sizes are in the 1GB to 100GB range (bioinformatics).

Here's a contrived but runnable example:

```
function cmd1 { sed -r 's/[246]/x/g'; }
function cmd2 { sed -r 's/[135]/-/g'; }
function cmd3 { paste $1 $2; }
seq 10 > input
cmd3 <(cmd1 < input) <(cmd1 < input | cmd2)  # cmd1 runs twice
```

output

```
1       -
x       x
3       -
x       x
5       -
x       x
7       7
8       8
9       9
10      -0
```

Not sure if this is helpful, but I want data to flow like this:

```
input --> cmd1 ---> cmd2  -->|
                |            |--> cmd3  --> output
                ------------>|
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43536 came close, but not quite.

Comment: Is using variables not an option?

Comment: the intermediate files can be >10GB in size.

Comment: this might be worth including in your original question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, possibly?

```bsh
rm -f fifo
mkfifo fifo

cmd1 <input | tee fifo | cmd2 | cmd3 fifo /dev/stdin >output
```

This creates a named pipe called `fifo`.  The first command writes to both the named pipe and the second command's standard input using `tee`.  The third command reads from the named pipe and standard input.

None of the intermediate data is stored on disk, but the pipeline would likely deadlock if `cmd3` does not consume from the named pipe before the pipe buffer is full, or if `cmd2` produces very little data compared to the amount of data it consumes (and, crucially, not producing enough for `cmd3` to consume from `fifo` before that pipe's buffer is full).  You could *possibly* remedy this by using something like `pv` to buffer the data from the named pipe, as with `cmd3 <( pv --quiet <fifo ) /dev/stdin`, or at the writer site with `tee >( pv --quiet >fifo )` (or some variation thereof).

Comment: How does the "deadlock" arise? `cmd1` fails(?) to handle(?) the scenario where its output file handle is temporarily(?) full?

Comment: @obk If `cmd2` produces very little data compared to what it reads, for example, or if `cmd3` does not read enough from `fifo`, allowing the pipe buffer to fill, which stops `tee` from being able to write to `fifo` and to `cmd2`.